# something like if statement for assignation

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is more like general question: Is there a way to assign a value like an if statement? I have a dictionary and I want to check if *key* exists and then assign. For example:

```
if((_attr.val = [self.dic objectForKey:@"name"]))
```

And i know that if *key* exist in _attr.val i will get object, if not i will get null. Great, but if statemant requires to_do_something after it, but in my case this is it - all what i want to do.

This is probably a silly question, but i'm having trouble with finding a solution.

I want to find something like ASSERT() known from c++.

Comment: I don't understand; you want to assign a value like an `if` statement but don't want to do the thing after the `if` statement?  How about not using an `if` statement?

Comment: I want to find something like ASSERT() from c++.

Comment: What about `NSAssert()`?

Comment: Great! NSAssert do the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` **makes sense when you want to create a conditional path**. In this case you just want to assign the value to `_attr.val`, still you should check if everything went was you expected. I would go with:

```
_attr.val = [self.dic objectForKey:@"name"]
if(!_attr.val){
  // Conditional case for a nil value.
}
```

If it really doesn't matter the end result (either a value or nil) just go:

```
_attr.val = [self.dic objectForKey:@"name"]
```

Either way, if you started this question with the `if` in mind it seems that you want to make some sort of check.

With `NSAssert`:

```
_attr.val = [self.dic objectForKey:@"name"]
NSAssert(_attr.val,@"Value is nil");
```

Comment: And if the user compiles with `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS`?

Comment: No, the code will break because `_attr.val` won't be assigned, and user will have a hard time finding this bug using the code you have provided.

Comment: You are right, if the `NSAssert`isn't allowed then the `attr.val` will be nil. So should the if be kept and the `NSAssert` out?

Comment: I don't see an edit?  But it should assign outside the `NSAssert()` and just check the value within the `NSAssert()`.

Comment: Check now. if it's according to what you said.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13513/discussion-between-jacky-boy-and-trojanfoe)